# sharing variables between 2 packages in R

Tags: r, variables, package

I have created 2 packages in R. The variables in one package are using in functions of the other package. So i declared variables globally like `var <<- "value"`. Now every functions are working properly. But the variables are now accessible to everyone. If the value of variable is changed by any user, lot of functions wont work properly. Is it possible to create a variable and use that variable only within some particular packages?

Comment: See if this is useful: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html

Comment: Why don't you explicitly pass variables between the functions in your packages?

Comment: @hadley: lot of variables are using inside each functions.so it is not a good way to pass all variables to every functions.

Comment: If there are many variables to pass around, you can also put them in one config object, i.e. a `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the settings in `options` instead of variables in the `.GlobalEnv`. You can use `options` as a key-value storage or assign e.g. a `list` to a key (maybe your package's name) like I do in [pander package](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/options.R). As you can see I even created some helper functions to update/query those list elements.

Quick example:

```
> options(foo = list(a = pi, b = 1:3))
> getOption('foo')
$a
[1] 3.141593

$b
[1] 1 2 3

> getOption('foo')['a']
$a
[1] 3.141593
```

Comment: Cool.  Tho' even this won't stop a determined user from modifying the values via the same mechanism :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Of course, just as nothing else would :) I mean you could store the values in the package namespace or any other place, the user would always have the option to override that - except for some situation where you forbid that e.g. with [sandboxR](http://hackme.rapporter.net/)

Comment: this is a cool method. what about the following method?
> url <- "http://mytext.com"
> file <- "This is the content I downloaded"
> cacheEnv <- new.env()
> assign(url, file, envir=cacheEnv)
> get(url, envir=cacheEnv)

Comment: @DinoopNair: IMHO I user would never overwrite something set in `options` by chance, on the other hand: a user can overwrite *anything* in R on purpose (even in package namespace - which would be a safer solution to store your variables instead of some random environment).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by creating new environment. http://digitheadslabnotebook.blogspot.in/2011/06/environments-in-r.html

```
>cacheEnv <- new.env()
> url <- "http://mytext.com"
> file <- "This is the content I downloaded"
> cacheEnv <- new.env()
> assign(url, file, envir=cacheEnv)
> get(url, envir=cacheEnv)
[1] "This is the content I downloaded"
```

The users cannot edit variables directly. They can edit the variables only using the name of the environment.